# Excel: calculate average of column B for same values of column A where only all values of column B to corresponding same A value is present

Tags: excel, row

I have two columns of values. Column A all have a series of numbers which function as identifiers, column B have values ranging from 1 to 5 and also blank values. I would like to calculate the average of column B for each group of identifiers in column A but only if all values in column B for the corresponding identifier in column A are present (column A is sorted). I've included an image:
[excel list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEcmY.jpg)

As the image shows value 2877040366 has all values in column B filled but the value above it 351856821 has not. Is it possible to have in column C the rows repeatedly show the average of all values in column B for 2877040366 but not for 351856821.

Comment: Averageif function should help you

Comment: Not sure if averageif is enough here since it should not count if there is blanks. But do you accept VBA? Seems much easier to build a VBA UDF for this.

Comment: If VBA will work then yes, it's been a while since I used that. Tried averageif but had no luck.

Comment: Used averageifs to add the additional criteria to not include blanks: =AVERAGEIFS(B:B,A:A,"a",B:B,"<>"&"")

Comment: I seem to be getting a #DIV/0! error on that formula

Comment: Is it possible that you have all blanks for that particular value?

Comment: The error occurs on all cases, partially blanks, fully filled and also all blanks. Perhaps I should have mentioned this before, all blanks can be present as well.

Comment: What about the identifiers? Are they actual numbers or numbers stored as text? You can test with =isnumber.

Comment: They are actual numbers, I made sure to format them as such in excel as well. =isnumber returns true

Comment: My bad. You are supposed to change the "a" to A1 (If entering in C1). I was testing it out and forgot to edit my formula before posting as a comment. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in C1 and drag it down:

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(B:B,A:A,A1,B:B,"<>"&""),0)
```

With the above formula if there is no identifier for a value (all are blank), it will return a 0. You can modify the above formula to further suit your needs.

**EDIT:**

Try the following to return a value ONLY if all the identifiers are there:

```
=IF(AVERAGEIFS(B:B,A:A,A1,B:B,"<>"&"")=SUMIF(A:A,A1,B:B)/COUNTIF(A:A,A1),AVERAGEIFS(B:B,A:A,A1,B:B,"<>"&""),"")
```

Comment: This indeed gives me average values grouped by the value in column A. However it gives average values of all groups while I'm searching for only average values where column B (in relation to the value of column A) are all filled in.

Comment: @Nick Kyndt Can you please give the expected output for 2877040366 and 351856821?

Comment: For 2877040366 calculated value is 2,857, expected value is 2,857. For 351856821 the calculate value is 2,571 but the expected value cannot be determined yet since not all B values filled in. I have no need for an average of an incomplete set hence the reason for the needed omission.

Comment: So you only want the average if all the values are filled? Otherwise you want a blank?

Comment: Yes. The calculation is correct, there only needs to be an added exclusion.

Comment: @Nick Kyndt Kindly check the edited answer if it suits your need.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was searching for. Thank you for your persistent effort.